# Cython/Armadillo error: scipy.sparse.csc_matrix to SpMat conversion

Tags: scipy, cython, sparse-matrix, armadillo

I'm currently wrapping the Armadillo library in Cython and have some trouble to convert scipy.sparse.csc_matrix in Python through Cython to the sparse matrix class from Armadillo.

The function to do so is actually like this :

```
cdef inline SpMat[double] * sp_to_spmatp(X):
    cdef np.ndarray[int, ndim = 1, mode = 'c'] col_ptrs = X.indptr
    cdef np.ndarray[int, ndim = 1, mode = 'c'] row_indices = X.indices
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim = 1, mode = 'c'] values = X.data
    cdef SpMat[double] *p_spRes = new SpMat[double](<int*> &row_indices[0], <int*> &col_ptrs[0], <double*> &values[0], X.shape[0], X.shape[1])
    return p_spRes
```

where `X` is the sparse matrix from scipy and `p_spRes` the sparse matrix from Armadillo.

By building it I get this error:

> arma_wrapper.cpp:3418:549: error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘arma::SpMat::SpMat(int*, int*, double*, int&, int&)’

along with:

```
    Armadillo/include/armadillo_bits/SpMat_bones.hpp:103:10: note: candidate: template<class T1, class T2, class T3> arma::SpMat<eT>::SpMat(const arma::Base<long long unsigned int, T1>&, const arma::Base<long long unsigned int, T2>&, const arma::Base<eT, T3>&, arma::uword, arma::uword)
   inline SpMat(const Base<uword,T1>& rowind, const Base<uword,T2>& colptr, const Base<eT,T3>& values, const uword n_rows, const uword n_cols);
          ^~~~~
Armadillo/include/armadillo_bits/SpMat_bones.hpp:103:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
arma_wrapper.cpp:3418:549: note:   mismatched types ‘const arma::Base<long long unsigned int, T1>’ and ‘int*’
 ].strides)))), ((double *)(&(*__Pyx_BufPtrCContig1d(__pyx_t_5numpy_double_t *, __pyx_pybuffernd_values.rcbuffer->pybuffer.buf, __pyx_t_8, __pyx_pybuffernd_values.diminfo[0].strides)))), __pyx_t_10, __pyx_t_11);
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ^
```

which makes me think that some type casts may be incorrect.

If anyone does know anything about it, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Get rid of the `<int*>` casts - they aren't needed are are just likely to hide real errors. 2) What constructors do you believe `SpMat[double]` should have, and how have you wrapped these in Cython?

Comment: @DavidW `SpMat` is wrapped this way:
`cdef extern from "Armadillo/include/armadillo" namespace "arma" nogil:

    cdef cppclass SpMat[eT]:

        SpMat() nogil
        SpMat(unsigned int, unsigned int) nogil
        SpMat(int*, int*, eT*, int, int) nogil`

thinking the issue might be here: 
`SpMat(int*, int*, eT*, int, int)` 
with its equivalent in C++: 
`template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
  inline SpMat(const Base<uword,T1>& rowind, const Base<uword,T2>& colptr, const Base<eT,T3>& values, const uword n_rows, const uword n_cols);`

Comment: Looking at [the documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat) you seem to be trying to use "form 4" of the constructor. It looks like this takes Armadillo `uvec` instead of pointers. Therefore, you should be trying to work out how to create a `uvec` from a pointer.

Comment: I managed to get it working with `uvec` being of type `Col[uword]` and `uword` being of type `long long unsigned int`, by doing so in the class definition: `SpMat(Col[uword], Col[uword], Col[double], unsigned int, unsigned int) nogil` and building the Col constructor. Thank you for your help!